# An integral on a metric ball

Tags: real-analysis

Let $d$ be a positive integer. We consider a norm $\rho$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$.
For $r>0$, we define
\begin{align*}
B_\rho(r)=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^d \mid \rho(y)<r\}.
\end{align*}
Then, can we compute the following integral ?:
\begin{align}
\int_{B_\rho(r)}|\rho(z)|^2\,m(dz),\tag{$\ast$}
\end{align}
where $m$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^d$. If $\rho$ is the Euclidean norm, the integral is equal to
\begin{align*}
\int_{B_\rho(r)}\rho(z)^2\,m(dz)=\int_{0}^r \int_{S^{d-1}}u^2 u^{d-1}\,du\,\sigma(ds).
\end{align*}
Here, $\sigma$ denotes the Lebesgue measure on the $d-1$-dimensional sphere. Even for a general norm $\rho$, such a formula exists?

Comment: No, the integral on a ball is $dr$ times surface area only if the boundary of the ball is perpendicular to the radius vector.  Try a simple case, say in $\mathbb R^2$ use $\rho(x,y) = |x|+|y|$ and see what happens.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for your comment. I'm afraid that the content of the question will change, but is there sa formula that holds even in the general case?